# Show that a restricted function is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with the property that

$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x,y)| dx \leq 5 $

for all $y > 0$. Show that $x \mapsto f(x,0)$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ and satisfies

$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x,0)| dx \leq 5$.

My try:

Let $(y_{n})$ be sequence in $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ such that $\lim_{n} y_{n} = 0$ and define $f_{n} = f(x,y_{n})$. Now $(f_{n})$ is a sequence of measurable functions and since $ \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x,y)| dx \leq 5 $ for all $ y > 0 $, $ |f_{n}| \leq g $ $\mu$-a.e. for some $[0, + \infty]$-valued integrable function $g$.

Since $\lim_{n} f_{n} = f(x,0)$, the Dominated Convergence Theorem applies. Therefore,

$ \lim_{n} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{n} dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f dx$, and since all functions are continuous, we have by continuity that

$\lim_{n} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y_{n}) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,0) dx \leq 5$.

Is this correct or is some steps incorrect? Are there easier ways of proving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more elementary approach (in the sense of avoiding DCT). Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, and let $M > 0$.  Since $f$ is continuous it is  uniformly continuous on compact sets and in particular there exists $\delta > 0$ with the property that $|y| \le \delta$ implies $|f(x,y) - f(x,0)| < \frac{\epsilon}{M}$ for all $|x| \le M$.  Then
$$
\int_{[-M,M]} |f(x,0) - f(x,\delta)| \, dx < \epsilon.
$$
We conclude that
$$ 
\int_{[-M,M]} |f(x,0)| \, dx < \epsilon + 5.
$$
Now let $M \to \infty$, and finally $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks, that was certainly easier, however, are there any errors in my "solution" or is it valid? I am prepairing for an exam so it is interesting for me to see how good (or bad) my own approach is.

Comment: To apply DCT you need to show that the majorant $g$ is integrable.  The least $g$ that works is $g(x) = \sup_n f_n(x,y_n)$ but I'm not sure at first glance if this is integrable or not.

Comment: yes, you are right. Just because the integral is bounded for each $f_{n}$ I guess that $ \sup_{n} f_{n}$ need not to be integrable.